# Drag and drop list, best performance to save the order from the elements in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

i'm working on a draggable list, we need to save the order or priority from the elements, but i have problem with the performance.

We have three types of elements, buttons, images and videos, the user can add elements and reorder.

My question is, how can i have the best performance, imagine that in the future we can have 100 000 pages, each page with 15 elements between images, videos and buttons and the database should be updated every movement with ajax?

**First option:** Creating 4 tables, images, videos, buttons and priority, having a relationship between them and their priority.
[First option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcGLb.jpg)

**Second option:** Create only one table called "elements" with an attribute called priority and three attributes, "is_video", "is_image", "is_button".
[Second option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/072co.png)

Comment: Have you tried checking whether there are currently any problems? "The best performance" might have many moving parts, like: does your application itself work fast? Would you probably update the data solely within your application and send a bunch of `UPDATE` queries to the database, as other parts might be involved?

Comment: Are you reordering a "few" items on each page?  Or you reordering 100K pages?  Or 100K*15 items?

Comment: @NicoHaase the application should be developed in laravel livewire, and i need to update every movement in the drag and drop.

Comment: @RickJames only i need update the items that belong to one page, but several users can modifiy at the same time, so each user have his own page, and only each user can modify his own items, they have an interval from 2 items to 40 items.

Answer (score 1):

Probably having a single table with the order of items will be the best because you operate on a single table for all reordering operations. Something like that can work well:

```
SORTED_ITEMS
--------------
PAGE      VARCHAR   -- Identifier of the page
ID_ITEM   VARCHAR   -- Identifier of the item
POSITION  INT       -- the position of the item inside the page
```

Than you can have an ITEMS table holding all the data that probably don't change during a reordering.

```
ITEMS
-----------------
ID_ITEM   VARCHAR PK - THe primary key of the item
TYPE      VARCHAR    - The type of the item (video, image, button...)
...                  - All other fields related to an item
```

This solution perform well because the sorting operation doesn't affect a big table and gives you the ability to add new kind of items in the future without changing the code for sorting them.

If the number of items per page is limited to a reasonable number you can also create a table for PAGES like the following

```
 PAGES
 ------
 ID_PAGE    VARCHAR
 ITEMS      VARCHAR
```

where ITEMS holds the list of items in a format that can be easily handled by your code, for example in JSON like `["ITEM1", "ITEM2", "ITEM3", ...]`
This let you make a reordering with a single update on the database but an extra effort on the software to generate the ITEMS string. You can also change it to a different format like `ITEM1,ITEM2,ITEM3` or `ITEM1|ITEM2|ITEM3`.

This format helps you also finding pages containing a specific ITEM because you can do a simple `SELECT ID_PAGE FROM PAGES WHERE ITEMS LIKE '%<ID_ITEM>%'`

Comment: Thank you @Davide, if i use the first method and i have 100 000 pages * 15 items = 1 500 000 records in the order tables, i'll need modify 15 records every user movement, it's would be efficient? And how do you store the type in items table? With a number for example 1, 2, 3 or directly with the name, for example image, video and buttons or in other table called types and with relation?

Comment: I believe that updating about 15 rows out of 1.5M, though possible, would be clumsy and somewhat slow.

Comment: @RickJames there is nothing special in updating only 15 rows in a table holding 1.5M records. The update must be done by primary key so it is quite fast. Eventually, it is possible to partition the table if the speed is not enough, but I suggest to do it only after experiencing low performances

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO - Sometimes getting the 15 PKs is the costly part.  The optimal way is to have the PK  _start with_ the column(s) needed by the `WHERE` for both _finding and updating_ the 15 rows.  (Until the schema is settled, it is hard to be more specific.)

Answer (score 0):

`Items` table contains an `AUTO_INCREMENT` number unique to each sortable item on the pages.

`Pages` table contains a `VARCHAR` with a commalist of the ids of items.

The UI fetches that commalist, plus other info about the items for the user to rearrange.  After each rearrangement, the list of ids is sent back to the server (via AJAX).  Also sent back is the `page_id`.  Then is is a simple

```
UPDATE Pages
    SET items = ?
    WHERE page_id = ?
```

Note that `items` is both the list of items and the ordering of those items.  When "building" a page, `split()` (`explode()`, or whatever) the ids apart for further fetching.  Or simply feed into an `IN(...)` list.

This will fetch the items for one page, and deliver them in the current order:

```
SELECT *
    FROM Items
    WHERE item_id IN ($item_list)
    ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(item_id, ?)
```

(Caveat:  An `IN` list cannot be bound via `?` in most APIs, you must construct the SQL after verifying that the list has not been hacked.  Checking with regexp `/^[,0-9]+$/` should suffice.)

My `Items` forces you to have a single table for items, at least for having a way to have unique `item_ids`.  You *may* also require 3 other tables -- depending on schema details.

**Only Rearrange?**

If the user is *only* allowed to rearrange the items on one page, ...

Let's say, the page has items 51,4,7.  This came from a `SELECT` that was used to build the UI.

If the user *just* rearranges them to, say, 7,51,4, take each string, `explode` it, sort numerically, then `implode` it.  Compare them.  Since both say 4,7,51, it is valid to `UPDATE` the `items` column.  (Note:  The "old" `items` should be re-fetched from the table just to make sure nothing hacked in the API call.)

A hacker may try for 99,33.  But that will sort to 33,99, which won't match 4,7,51.  (Ditto for a legitimate user trying to move items out of or into the page.)

Comment: Thank you Rick, what about if in the front end the user modify the string for the items? I.e, if i have the original string, with ids: "4,7,9," but the user modify this string to "4,16,92", how can i make sure that the items belong to this page and not to another page? Do i need to do another query checking the list having the page id in the items table?

Comment: @CarlosValdesWeb - My addition covers "only allowed to rearrange on a single page".

Comment: Thank's Rick, what do you think about to store the position in items field and only store the position 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000 to have more gaps between each item and after only store for example 1500, after 1250, etc, or maybe store a string in field position like AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD and if i need to re order i can to add AAB or AAC etc? Could be more efficient that your solution?

Comment: @CarlosValdesWeb - In the extreme case, you would run out of numbers after 10 inserts.  (log 1024 base 2 = 10).  My approach avoids using numbers for ordering; instead it uses position in a string.